# Android Studio Mouse Behaviour

Tags: android, mouseover

Using AS 3.0.1 and Win 10 Pro. Scrolling over text in code or XML (ie; everywhere) the text will many times get scrambled or the highlighting will turn off and I have to try highlighting the text again. Sometimes this works and other times I have to try 3 or 4 times.  Very annoying. Mouse drivers are current (LogiTechM510). Using k/b to highlight works fine.  Idea J traditionally has always been k/b (so is AS) oriented and I wonder if this is a possible reason. Anybody seen this behaviour, or know of a solution (except tossing the mouse and using k/b)?

Comment: similar things occured to me i think, did you try restart and invalidate the cache?

Comment: Yes, done all that and problem remains.  Very annoying and time wasting. Maybe I should learn to use the keyboard.

Comment: I would reinstall and look for similar bugs in the Idea IDE. There are also some config settings. If that still not works, try to find out and download a version of studio that works for you..

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the mouse was shot. Replaced it and now all is ok.